# Why is laptop screen called eDP1?

Tags: xorg, laptop, monitors, xrandr

In my new laptop, using `i915` and the `intel` driver of Xorg, the laptop screen is called eDP1 in Randr

```
$ xrandr
eDP1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 277mm x 156mm
   1366x768      60.14 +  40.09  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1024x768      60.00* 
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   640x480       59.94
```

Why is it called `eDP1`? what does the "e" of `eDP1` stand for?

Answer (score 23):

> Why is it called eDP1?

Because it is an *[embedded display port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#eDP)* style adapter, and not a [video graphics array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_Graphics_Array) style one.